# Regular expression for optional commas with a 6 character limit

Tags: regex

I need a regex that allows numbers and optional commas, but the entire length cannot be greater than 6.

`^[0-9]+([,]*[0-9]+)*$` allows numbers and optional commas.

`^([0-9]+([,]*[0-9]+)*){0,6}$` does not limit the total length to 6.

Comment: Is that optional *commas* (plural) or just one comma?

Comment: It would be helpful to see some examples that match and other examples that don't match.

Comment: Can the comma be leading and/or trailing? Mulitple commas? Multiple commas in sequence? `,2,,3,` would be valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your regex engine supports lookahead assertions — most do — then you can write:

```
^(?=[0-9,]{1,6}$)[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$
```

The `(?=[0-9,]{1,6}$)` part is a "positive lookahead assertion", and means "looking forward from this point in the string, I see `[0-9,]{1,6}$`". So, in essence, the above regex is a combination of these two:

```
^[0-9,]{1,6}$
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$
```

and enforces them both.

(That said, it's likely to be clearer if you simply enforce the length restriction as a separate step, rather than incorporating the above into a single regex.)

Answer (score 0):

```
^([\,0-9]{0,6})$
```

This regex simply allows any of the characters (comma, zero through nine) zero through six times.

If you require that the input start with a number, use this:

```
^([0-9]{1}[\,0-9]{0,5})$
```

Comment: I imagine that the OP doesn't want the string to contain multiple commas in a row, or to end with a comma.

Comment: Perhaps not, though he did say ***commas*** as through it is permitted to have multiple.

Comment: @ruakh - Going by his regex sample, it is possible for `4,,5`, however, @JYelton - it also looks like it has to have digit bookends, but yours will match `4,,5,,`

Comment: Oh well, what can you do when OP's leave out detail?

Comment: I agree that OP left out important details, and I read `commas` in  plural form, too, but since he emphasized `optional` for commas, and not optional for numbers, it is, imho, wrong. Must contain at least one number, but not necessarily in the first position.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional ways -

```
^(?=.{1,6}$)\d+(?:,?\d)*$

^(?=.{1,6}$)\d(?:[,\d]*\d)?$
```